# Use log4j2 for multiple classes

Tags: java, log4j

I found many link that helped me building the logger. Some here in SO and others in other pages.

This answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624895/how-to-use-log4j-with-multiple-classes#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624895/how-to-use-log4j-with-multiple-classes#_=_) is the best that I have found.
It is already some years old thought and some things now are different.

***My goal is to have one single logger shared among all of the java classes that print messages to the log, both console and file.***

I am using LOG4J2: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

**main()**:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class App {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("GLOBAL");
    public static void main(){
        ...calling other classes
  }
}
```

**anyOtherClass**:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
public class secondClass {
    private final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("GLOBAL");
    public void writeLog(){
      LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "A simple string");
  }
}
```

**log4j.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="basePath">/var/log</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="fileLogger" fileName="${basePath}/myApp.log" filePattern="${basePath}/myApp-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>

       <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="java.util.logging.Logger" level="ALL" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="fileLogger" level="ALL" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="ALL" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I (more or less) know that I should use LogManager, truth is I should call it as:

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyApp.class);
```

or, in the **main()**, probably like this:

```
private static Logger LOGGER = null;

@BeforeClass
public static void setLogger() {
    System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile","log4j.xml");
    LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();
}
```

Because, I believe, using *LogManager* I can point the Log to the xml file for its settings.
But when I build it and run it, the CLI rage quits at the first ever LOG, reporting: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at myapp.modules.Database.<init>(Database.java:67)`

**Expected Result**:
All I want to do is being able to have the log on all of my classes and that this is written to a file.
I just can't get this working. And when I do not use LogManager, I only see the logs on console but no file is created.
I'm using both Windows and Linux (that's why /var/log/ but I change it to C:\ too).

**Other website I used**:
https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j2/configure-log4j2-for-junit/

[Log4J loggers for different classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842494/log4j-loggers-for-different-classes) <-- did not help me

..And many other search results are more than 6 years old.

**POM.xml**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: When using Log4j2, most of your imports for logging should reference classes in this package `org.apache.logging.log4j`. I think the problem lies there.

Comment: @neomega sorry I forgot to copy it, I'm using it already. Netbeans warns me when I miss something. I'm using `import java.util.logging.Logger;` and the POM is edited to to use log4j-api and log4j-core -> 2.10.0

Comment: @neomega I understood it now what you meant! I'm checking if my mistake is here. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're wrong on several levels: you're mixing JDK's logger with Log4j2's Logger, you're not logging to several appenders, etc.

Here's what you should do:

#### `/pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j2test</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is basically the only place where you have no error.

#### `/src/main/java/so47656300/App.java`

```
package so47656300;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class App {

  private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(App.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    logger.info("App.main - starting");
    new SecondClass();
    logger.info("App.main - ending");
  }
}
```

Here, your error was to use `java.util.logger.Logger` instead of `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger`.

#### `/src/main/java/so47656300/SecondClass.java`

```
package so47656300;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class SecondClass {

  private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(SecondClass.class);

  public SecondClass() {
    logger.info("SecondClass - starting");
    logger.info("SecondClass - ending");
  }
}
```

Here, your error was also to use the wrong `Logger` class. Use only classes from `org.apache.logging.log4j.*`.

#### `/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="basePath">/var/log</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="fileLogger" fileName="${basePath}/myApp.log" filePattern="${basePath}/myApp-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>

        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="fileLogger"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Here, your errors are the following:

1. Wrong file name: [Log4J 2 requires a name `log4j2.xml`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html). For your tests, create a file `/src/test/resources/log4j2-test.xml`.
2. You want only one logger, so use only one: the root one. You created several, but you don't need them.
3. Add appenders to the logger (the Root-one)

## Output

### Console

```
[INFO ] 2017-12-05 16:52:32.218 [main] App - App.main - starting
[INFO ] 2017-12-05 16:52:32.221 [main] SecondClass - SecondClass - starting
[INFO ] 2017-12-05 16:52:32.222 [main] SecondClass - SecondClass - ending
[INFO ] 2017-12-05 16:52:32.222 [main] App - App.main - ending
```

### `/var/log/myApp.log`

```
[INFO ] 2017-12-05 16:52:32.218 [main] App - App.main - starting
[INFO ] 2017-12-05 16:52:32.221 [main] SecondClass - SecondClass - starting
[INFO ] 2017-12-05 16:52:32.222 [main] SecondClass - SecondClass - ending
[INFO ] 2017-12-05 16:52:32.222 [main] App - App.main - ending
```

Comment: I have done literally everything you said, before you wrote it! I realized my errors thanks to the comment below my question. I wish to thank you for taking the time to reply! this is so kind and I appreciate it a lot! You helped me to rename the log4j.xml to log4j2.xml because I totally forgot to do it, this application had log4j 1,2 before and I am converting it.
Anyway, since 10 minutes I'm stuck here: `ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.`

Comment: @Nihvel I do not have that issue in my project. Try coming from the bases: put the `log4j2.xml` file in the `src/main/resources` folder. Copy it as `log4j2-test.xml` in the `src/test/resources` folder and edit that one for the tests you wish to perform.

Comment: It can not find the configuration file. But the file was renamed and the POM too: `<directory>src/main/resources</directory><targetPath>${project.build.directory}</targetPath><includes><include>log4j2.xml</include></includes>` so it should be all good! I just opened your answer. Yes, exactly what I did! Ok, I will try to read the codes better! thanks again!

Comment: I know it is correct what I have but it still can't find the file. StackOverflow is filled with question about this same topic, they say all the same: to put into src/main/resources; and it is what I did. But still nothing ... I accept your answer because the problem I asked was solved following these directives, but I'm still working on having the property file seen!

Comment: Found the "problem". My POM contains the directive for building both the tiny jar file with external lib/classes/etc.. and the fat-jar (all in one, weight ~16MB). The first is able to read the properties file and writes the log succesfully. The second not. I must find a way to let the fat-jar read the external properties file, like here: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775303/read-properties-file-outside-jar-file) but just tried and does not work.. (: damn.

Comment: FIXED and used version 3.1.0 of maven shade plugin: [FIX HERE](http://www.codepreference.com/2017/02/how-to-fix-log4j2-problem-with-maven-shade-plugin.html)

Comment: Good job on finishing this!